# Event Manager attach with wilcard

Tags: events, zend-framework2

To attach a new event to a listener I use a code as follow and works fine:

```
class Listener implements ListenerAggregateInterface
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\Stdlib\CallbackHandler[]
     */
    protected $listeners = array();

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function attach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        $sharedEvents      = $events->getSharedManager();

        $this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach('*', '*', array($this, 'log'));
    }

    public function detach(EventManagerInterface $events)
    {
        foreach ($this->listeners as $index => $listener) {
            if ($events->detach($listener)) {
                unset($this->listeners[$index]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function log($event)
    {
        // Log  feature here
    }
}
```

I want to associate only some actions, and not "*", for example associate actions that ends with ".post", something like this:

```
(...)
$this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach('*', '*.post', array($this, 'log'));
(...)
```

But doesn't works, how can I do something like that? (To avoid listening to all actions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is you can't.

You can however listen to multiple events by handing the attach method an array of event names, eg..

```
$this->listeners[] = $sharedEvents->attach('*', 
    array('register.post', 'edit.post', 'create.post'), 
    array($this, 'log')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a wildcard listener that listens to `*` and filter by event name in your log function like this:

```
public function log($event)
{

    // Get event name
    $eventName = $event->getName();

    // Perform any string comparison you like here
    if($eventName === 'register'){ 

        // Do something
    }
}
```

You can also have a look at my zf2-event-logger module code on GitHub for more code:

https://github.com/jvandemo/zf2-event-logger

Comment: I'd advise caution when listening to all events, some events are expected to return a response, and listeners that return void or some other unexpected value in such instances can cause unpredictable results/errors. (speaking from experience here :-D )

Comment: Hi Crisp, could you please elaborate and give an example? Thanks!

Comment: @jurgen-vand-de-moere Take the `ModuleManager::::EVENT_LOAD_MODULE_RESOLVE` event triggered by `loadModuleByName` here -> https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/blob/master/library/Zend/ModuleManager/ModuleManager.php#L167-182 . As you can see it's expecting a listener to return a module object instance and that the last result in the collection will be the module instance. If you've attached a listener which triggers after the actual `ModuleResolverListener`, the last result will not be a module, it will be whatever your listener returned, causing a `Module could not be initialized` exception.

Comment: Example of what @Crisp said: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428778/zend-session-container-session-validation-failed-exception-objectclosure-zf