# Zend\Session\Container Session validation failed exception -- Object(Closure) ZF2

Tags: php, session, zend-framework2

I'm trying to use authentication and sessions in a ZF2 App. So far I have the follow code:

In my Module.php:

```
// (...) rest of code

public function getServiceConfig()
    {
        return array(
                'factories' => array(
                        // (...) Other factories

                        // Authentication Service
                        'AuthService' => function($sm) {
                            $dbAdapter           = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                            $dbTableAuthAdapter  = new DbTable($dbAdapter,
                                'sec_user','login','password');

                            $authService = new AuthenticationService();
                            $authService->setAdapter($dbTableAuthAdapter);

                            return $authService;
                        },
                ),
        );
    }

// (...) rest of code
```

Then in my Controller Login action I have:

```
use Zend\Session\Container;

// (...) rest of code

    public function loginAction()
    {
       $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()
                  ->setIdentity('testlogin')
                  ->setCredential('testpass');

        $auth_result = $this->getAuthService()->getAdapter()->authenticate();

        if ($auth_result->isValid()) {
            $session = new Container(); // Exception line
            $session->login = 'testlogin';

            // (...) other code
        }
    }
// (...) rest of code
```

The code works fine, validate the credentials successfully but when I try to save some value to SESSION with the simplest example I found in documentation, it fails. The line:

```
$session = new Container();
```

Is triggering this Exception:

```
Session validation failed
```

What else can I test? Any idea about what I'm  doing wrong will be appreciated.

Bellow is the full trace:

```
File:
/var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/SessionManager.php:111


Message:

Session validation failed


Stack trace:

#0 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Session/AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionManager->start()
#1 /var/www/sismedical/Server/module/Security/src/Security/Controller/AuthController.php(100): Zend\Session\AbstractContainer->__construct()
#2 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractActionController.php(83): Security\Controller\AuthController->loginAction()
#3 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#4 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#5 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#6 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php(117): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#7 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/DispatchListener.php(114): Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController->dispatch(Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Request), Object(Zend\Http\PhpEnvironment\Response))
#8 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\DispatchListener->onDispatch(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#9 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#10 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/EventManager/EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
#11 /var/www/sismedical/Server/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Application.php(309): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('dispatch', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Object(Closure))
```

Comment: Do you by any chance have an event listener listening to all events  triggered by all classes? (ie `$sharedEvents->attach('*', '*', .. )` Shot in the dark, but I know for sure that such a listener will result in the above error.

Comment: @Crisp I haven't enough words to thank you :) please add the Answer to accept it.

Comment: Glad I could be of help, it was a real pain to debug when it happened to me :o[. Answer added ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Attaching an event listener to listen to all events triggered by all classes `$sharedEvents->attach('*', '*', .. )` will cause this error message.

You have to be really careful what you attach listeners to, since some listeners are expecting a specific response (in this case a boolean indicating if session is valid). A listener that wasn't designed to handled the event, such as a log listener, will typically not return a response, which in this case is seen as a validation failure.

Comment: You saved my day. Thanks and +1 for you.