# zf2 session validation failed

Tags: php, validation, session, zend-framework2, doctrine

I am using zf2, rbcomments, doctrine, zfcuser and samuser entity...I have a problem, before onbootstrap, my application throws "session validation failed" error. I do not use sessions anywhere except authentication (which is done by zfcuser, not manually). here is the call stack:

```
Additional information:
Zend\Session\Exception\RuntimeException
File:
C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\SessionManager.php:111
Message:
Session validation failed
Stack trace:
#0 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Session\AbstractContainer.php(78): Zend\Session\SessionManager->start()
#1 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session.php(63): Zend\Session\AbstractContainer->__construct('Zend_Auth', NULL)
#2 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db.php(116): Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session->__construct()
#3 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db.php(42): ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db->getStorage()
#4 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService.php(134): ZfcUser\Authentication\Storage\Db->isEmpty()
#5 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zf-commons\zfc-user\src\ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserIdentity.php(23): Zend\Authentication\AuthenticationService->hasIdentity()
#6 [internal function]: ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserIdentity->__invoke()
#7 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(400): call_user_func_array(Object(ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserIdentity), Array)
#8 C:\wamp\www\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(118): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->__call('zfcUserIdentity', Array)
#9 C:\wamp\www\module\Application\view\layout\layout.phtml(118): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->zfcUserIdentity()
#10 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer.php(507): include('C:\\wamp\\www\\mod...')
#11 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\View\View.php(205): Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#12 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy.php(102): Zend\View\View->render(Object(Zend\View\Model\ViewModel))
#13 [internal function]: Zend\Mvc\View\Http\DefaultRenderingStrategy->render(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#14 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(468): call_user_func(Array, Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#15 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\EventManager\EventManager.php(207): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->triggerListeners('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent), Array)
#16 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(347): Zend\EventManager\EventManager->trigger('render', Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#17 C:\wamp\www\vendor\zendframework\zendframework\library\Zend\Mvc\Application.php(300): Zend\Mvc\Application->completeRequest(Object(Zend\Mvc\MvcEvent))
#18 C:\wamp\www\public\index.php(26): Zend\Mvc\Application->run()
#19 {main}
```

more info that could help (the only listener yet to be added):

```
public function onBootstrap(MvcEvent $mvcEvent)
{
    $zfcServiceEvents = $mvcEvent->getApplication()->getServiceManager()->get('zfcuser_user_service')->getEventManager();
    $zfcServiceEvents->attach('register', function($e) use($mvcEvent) {

        $app = $mvcEvent->getApplication();
        $sm = $app->getServiceManager();
        $user = $e->getParam('user');
        $entityManager = $sm->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
        $roleRepo = $entityManager->getRepository('SamUser\Entity\Role');
        $defaultRole = $roleRepo->findOneBy(array('id'=>2));
        $user->addRole($defaultRole);
    });
}
```

I tried a few things (like printing the session in vendor, nothing seems wrong)...any ideas?

P.s. I suspect it has to do with the layout, where I am trying to see if user has identity by using `if(!$this->zfcUserIdentity()){`

Comment: possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428778/zend-session-container-session-validation-failed-exception-objectclosure-zf

Comment: its not a duplicate...i do not use sessions at all, he uses session container

Comment: i fixed it by removing the bjyauthorize module and installing it again

Comment: if u use third application modules you should look there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This just happened to me when Google Chrome updated, changing its UserAgent string.  Session validation notices, and throws the exception.  Look in your config for `['session_manager']['validators']` and remove `HttpUserAgent`.

*Your existing session still needs to be toasted by removing its cookie*, then going forward this UserAgent check won't occur.

(What would be nice is to just quietly start a new session without the big explosion.  I'm looking into it...)

Comment: I've created a ZF2 Composer module to behave nicely on invalid session.  That's here: https://packagist.org/packages/beaucal/beaucal-invalid-session