# Zend\Authentication\Storage\Session Session validation failed, any ideas?

Tags: session, zend-framework2

I have a simple authentication code like on a zf2 application

```
$this->auth = new AuthenticationService(new Session($this->namespace));
```

and the external modules used are

- ZendDeveloperTools
- BjyProfiler

Everytime, I try to authenticate, like

```
$this->auth->authenticate($adapter)
```

I get a "Session validation failed" error message.

When I disable ZendDeveloperTools module, I do not get this error but couldnot fix. I also checked [Zend\Session\Container Session validation failed exception — Object(Closure) ZF2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17428778/zend-session-container-session-validation-failed-exception-objectclosure-zf), but I do not have anywhere on my code

> $sharedEvents->attach('*', '*', .. )

as suggested by [Crisp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1112089/crisp)

Answer (score 2):

i had a same problem.
Look at:

```
ZendDeveloperTools/Listener/EventLoggingListenerAggregate.php Line: 64

$events->attach($this->identifiers, '*', array($this,'onCollectEvent'), 
Profiler::PRIORITY_EVENT_COLLECTOR);
```

i uncomment it, then i don't get the error.

Hope it was helpful.